# How can I search a list of objects that contains a list of objects for the first entry that contains an element matching my search criteria?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of `IJapaneseDictionaryEntry` objects:

```
public interface IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    int Sequence { get; }
    IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; }
    IEnumerable<IReading> Readings { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISense> Senses { get; }
}
```

Where each object contains a list of `IKanji` objects

```
public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; }
}
```

Here's the list:

```
List<IJapaneseDictionaryEntry> entries = dictionary.GetEntries().ToList();
```

If this was a simple list then I know how to search it.

But what I would like to do is to search for the first `IJapaneseDictionaryEntry` object where there the `IEnumerable<Kanji>` object inside that contains the text `犬`

Can anyone give me any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
entries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Kanjis.Any(t => t.Text?.Contains("犬")));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
entries.First(x => x.Kanjis.Any(y => y.Text.Contains("犬")))
```

Comment: this could throw an exception if there are no `IJapaneseDictionaryEntry` object in `entries` that have Kanjis with 犬 Text, or if `Kanji.Text` is null